# convert the array to object in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

Hello everyone I am new in meanstack. I want to fetch records from mongodb which ids match. I send an array but it doesn't work properly. Please help me to solve this issue.

Following is the code that describe my sending parameter in angular side.

```
 var output = [];
 var i = 0;

 angular.forEach(statedata, function(element) {
     output.push(element._id);
 });

 $rootScope.stateconddata = output;

 resourcedata(this.baseurl + '/getalldata?usertype=' + type + '&country=' + $rootScope.country + '&state=' + $rootScope.stateconddata + '&city=' + $rootScope.citydata + '&id=' + id, {}, {
     query: {
         method: 'GET',
         headers: {
             Accept: 'application/json'
         }
     }
 }).$promise.then(function(response) {});
```

in NodeJS side I wrote the query like below:

```
 if (querydata.state.length > 0) {
     Queryset.where('state').in(querydata.state);
 }
```

when I wrote above code in below way then it works fine for single element but doesn't work for multiple elements.

```
if (querydata.state.length > 0) {
     Queryset.where('state').in([querydata.state]);
}
```

In short I want to pass elements like below:

```
["582993205d40e67e09f5df28","682993205d40e67e09f5df28"]
```

not like

```
582993205d40e67e09f5df28,682993205d40e67e09f5df28
```

Comment: how about using `Queryset.where('state').in(querydata.state);` where `querydata.state` is array.

Comment: when i write Queryset.where(["582993205d40e67e09f5df28","682993205d40e67e09f5df28"]) then it working fine i want this kind of array

Answer (score 0):

if you need to conver array to Object in javascript  Way like this :

```
var x = ['ahmed','mostafa','ebrahem'];
var myObj = {};
for(var i = 0 ; i < x.length ; i++){
    myObj[i] = x[i];
}
```

if you log the myObj variable you will get this result

```
myObj = {
    0 : "ahmed",
    1: "mostafa",
    2: "ebrahem"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to sent data like this: 582993205d40e67e09f5df28,682993205d40e67e09f5df28

then u need to send as a string

```
var x = ['582993205d40e67e09f5df28','682993205d40e67e09f5df28'];
var myObj = "";
for(var i = 0 ; i < x.length ; i++){
    if(i == i.length){
      myObj += x[i];
    }
    else{
      myObj += x[i] + ", ";
    }
}
```

Comment: no suresh i don't want to send data like 582993205d40e67e09f5df28,682993205d40e67e09f5df28

Comment: i want to sent it like below way

Comment: state :["57d13f35458f525e4eb61189","67d13f35458f525e4eb61189"]

Comment: here state is the parameter or query string variable which will be catched in node  js and by writing the in query to fetch records from mongodb

Comment: u need to send as a array?

Comment: like this 
 
state :["57d13f35458f525e4eb61189","67d13f35458f525e4eb61189‌​"]

Comment: then url should be like this:  baseurl+ '&id=["something","something1"] ?

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate a little bit of that data.

`var array = "582993205d40e67e09f5df28,682993205d40e67e09f5df28".split(',');`

foo now is an object
[image]

Comment: Another way, in this function
 ```angular.forEach(statedata, function(element) {
     output.push(element._id);
 });```
the `element._id` should be the string by `element._id + ""`

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you serialize manualy the array in the query string. Leave Angular do the job for all the `GET` parameters, i.e. pass the parameters as an object:

```
resourcedata(this.baseurl + '/getalldata', {
    usertype: type,
    country: $rootScope.country,
    state: $rootScope.stateconddata,
    city: $rootScope.citydata,
    id: id
 }, {
    query: {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { Accept: 'application/json' }
    }
 })
```

This should serialize the `state` array in something like (assuming `state=['x', 'y']`:

> ...?state=x&state=y

And should be processed as an array on the server side.

You can read [the documentation on $resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) for the details on how to configure your service.